# curl: Could not resolve host: Authorization

Tags: rest, curl, oauth-2.0

I wrote this curl command which doesn't seem to work.

> curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT "Authorization: Bearer {token}" -d "{"login":"user1","password":"xxx"}" https://localhost:8443/users/user1 -k

I tried to change quotation marks but it doesn't work either. All I got is

> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Authorization
>
> {"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"Full authentication is required to access this resource"}

The Authorization works fine though. I'm sure the token is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The `-H` flag is missing in front of the Authorization header.

Try

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer {token}" \
-X PUT -d '{"login":"user1","password":"xxx"}' \
https://localhost:8443/users/user1 -k
```

Because that was missing it was not seeing that as a header, but part of the request URL.

To test, I decode with this in PHP:

```
var_dump(json_decode(stream_get_contents(fopen('php://input', 'r'))));
```

Comment: Now I get an error ""Could not read JSON: Unexpected character ('l' (code 108)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n"

Comment: The command mixed double quotes in the JSON data so it was being misinterpreted.  I put the JSON in single quotes so it should work now.

Comment: Now I get "Could not read JSON: Unexpected character (''' (code 39)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')"

Comment: Check your json at jsonlint.org

Comment: It says json is valid.

Comment: If I run the exact command pointing to a local script I can receive and decode the JSON just fine.  Maybe it's a problem on the remote end now.

Comment: What version of curl are you using?

Comment: I cannot get it to work. I still get "Could not read JSON: Unexpected character..." What kind of errors on the server side might cause a problem? I wrote a client in C# and the server seems to be working fine.